# Variable height dialog with scrollable content at max-height

Tags: css

I am trying to crate a vertically centered dialog with variable height. I'm using a technique with span element with `height: 100%` and `vertical-align:middle` within the container.

Now the dialog box has a `max-height:80%` set on it so that it doesn't take up the entire height of the container if it becomes small. When the container becomes small, the content are becomes smaller as well but I cannot get the content area to become scrollable when this happens..

Here is a [simplified version](http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/xMk7g/) in a fiddle.

### HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="overlay">
        <span id="mickey-mouse"></span>
        <div id="overlay-inner">
            <div id="overlay-title">Title</div>
            <div id="overlay-content">
                <div id="content">MAKE ME SCROLL!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
body, html {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#overlay {
    position: aboslute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
}

#mickey-mouse {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#overlay-inner {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 80%;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay-title {
    padding: 1em;
    height: 14px;
    background: #eee;
}

#overlay-content {
    padding: 1em;
    /* HOW TO MAKE THIS SCROLLABLE? */
}
```

Comment: No wonder, since you’re setting `overflow:hidden` … make that `auto` if you want scrollbars to appear for oversized content.

Comment: @CBroe where do I put `overflow:auto`? If I put it on `div#overlay-inner` then the scrollbar appears for the entire dialog, whereas I want it to appear only for the `div#overlay-content`.

Comment: Well then you have to give that a height, otherwise the content can’t flow over.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I know that, but it's kinda the point that it doesn't have the fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your fiddle code

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJMQg/)

Here's the modified css

```
    body, html {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#overlay {
    position: aboslute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
}

#mickey-mouse {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#overlay-inner {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 90%;
height: 90%;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 80%;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay-title {
    padding: 1em;
    height: 5%;
    background: #eee;
    }

#overlay-content {
    padding: 1em;
max-height: 80%;
    overflow:auto;
    }
```

Please try and let me know

EDIT:

three things have been done .

added overflow visible for content div. added overflow-auto for overlay-content

and set the height and width of overlay-inner, overlay-content in percentages

Comment: Please, don't post "spot the difference" answers.

Comment: Sorry i thought a solution was needed. :(

Comment: Solutions are encouraged by all means, but you should add at least a minimum explanation on what was done.

Comment: @Pavlo: Thanks. It's not quite what I want. I also need the dialog to remain centered and be as tall as content when content is at its full height. I think I'll just have to use JavaScript to achieve this. I'll upvote nonetheless because it's a good enough solution in most cases if you move the background property from overlay-innner to overlay-content.

Comment: for that content not to collapse after a certain height you would need to use min-height. Maybe some thing round a desired height you would not like to stretch

Comment: kind of this ... http://jsfiddle.net/FUfrH/ specifying proper height that not to be minimized beyond that .